# Image Visibility DataTrigger Set Default to False

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an image that need to be showed based on condition, is that attachment file or not. The problem is, I've set trigger that set the value of the condition, but seems like the condition isn't work and the value always set to true.

```
<Image
    Width="30"
    Height="30"                                                    
    Source="Resources/Images/chat_file_attach.png">
      <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AttachStat}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />                                                                   
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AttachStat}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

The question is. Is there any way to make the default value to false? I've set it to true on the `C#` looping data, whenever the condition is attachment included.

Comment: Or is that because the AttachStat is a boolean so I need a special treatment to process it?

Comment: How about the `DataContext` of the `Image` and how do you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: I don't set any DataContext on the C#.

Comment: So where is the `AttachStat` from?

Comment: I've added AttachStat on the looping of the data and it be like `AttachStat = True;`

Comment: Sorry I don't get what do you mean before.

Comment: There should be an object with an AttachStat property in the DataContext of the Image element. The DataContext is typically inherited from one of the parent elements of the Image, e.g. the Window. The class that declares the AttachStat property should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event when the property value changes. It's also not necessary to have two DataTriggers here. A Setter for the default value and one DataTrigger are sufficient.

Comment: ValueConverter would do this far better than overriding the the style and triggers collection if default style has been declared for the image.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I'd say the exact opposite. A Style in XAML with a DataTrigger is far better then a Binding Converter (but that is just an opinion). However, even with a Binding Converter the actual problem of a presumably missing DataContext wouldn't be solved.

Comment: @Clemens can you provide me an example the usage of it? Indeed, you explain clear enough but I can't find a way to implement it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that unless you show us your declaration of the AttachStat property and how it is supposed to be used in your code.

Comment: @Clemens I've implement INotifyPropertyChanged before, and also PropertyChanged too. I'll try it again now.

Comment: @Clemens, sure when you do not have any default style or complex inheritance with the styles and you want to add just one more trigger then things will work nicely. But when you do have complex style inheritance and want to add such trigger, then good luck in maintaining everything.

Comment: @Janne "when you do have complex style inheritance", so who's got that here? There's an Image element with a directly set Style. You're creating more confusion than necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in your output window and search for:
System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error

I think the AttachStat property is not available in the image's DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

Use a single `DataTrigger` and make sure that the `DataContext` of the `Image` has a public `AttachStat` property:

```
<Image x:Name="img" Width="30" Height="30" Source="Resources/Images/chat_file_attach.png">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AttachStat}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

---

```
img.DataContext = new YourClass();
...
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _attachStat;
    public bool AttachStat
    {
        get
        {
            return _attachStat;
        }

        set
        {
            _attachStat = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [BoolToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a Boolean to and from a Visibility value.

In the resource section:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
```

And the image:

```
<Image Width="30"
       Height="30"                                                    
       Source="Resources/Images/chat_file_attach.png"
       Visibility="{Binding AttachStat, 
             Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```